# What is the key combination to send a SIGSTOP signal on terminal?

Tags: unix, signals

It is not Ctrl+Z. That is for `SIGTSTP`. Also, `stty -a` shows ^S as the combination but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The "key combination" is `kill -STOP`.

Comment: @KeithThompson How would you enter that "key combination" on terminal when the process is ignoring `SIGTSTP`, `SIGQUIT` and `SIGINT`? How does one end such a process from terminal? It would've been quite handy to have a keyboard-shortcut for `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`.

Comment: @rootkea If you can open a new terminal or shell, type `kill -STOP PID`, where PID is the process ID of the process. As the accepted answer says, there is no keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no key combination to send SIGSTOP.

Control-S tells the terminal driver to suspend output, but does not send a signal to the process.  Control-Q resumes output.

Answer (score 0):

For this,

1. Open a new terminal/shell
2. Type `kill -STOP 111` but instead of 111 substitute the actual process ID (it will be a different number).
3. The SIGSTOP signal would be sent.

Unfortunately, there is no keyboard shortcut for sending SIGSTOP signal.