# Can I trap control-q and control-s in ruby?

Tags: ruby, signals

For some signals, like SIGINT, I can easily enough set up a trap to handle the signal and continue execution as I see fit.  I'd like to add typical behavior for ^q and ^s to a ruby command-line application that I'm fiddling with.  Is there a way to do this - particularly, one that is portable so I can use it in Windows, iOS, Linux and Solaris?

EDIT:

It turns out that the signals are never delivered to the process.  In fact, running strace on the process and on its parent process, a bash instance, showed that neither the process nor the parent were getting any indication of what was going on.  They're simply being suspended.

I may try to have a SIGALARM handler that fires once per second, checks to see if much more than a second has passed since the last alarm, and makes appropriate calls if it concludes that the process has been suspended.  There would be false positives on a heavily-loaded system.

Answer (score 1):

In irb enter `Signal.list`. It will list all the signals you should be able to trap.

Trap a signal in ruby:

```
Signal.trap("STOP") do
  # handle the signal
end
```

In the terminal enter `$ stty -a`.  It should list signals and their associated key combo (if they have one).

I believe ^s is usually `stop` and ^q is `start`.

Although according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8513948/1279177), those key combos do not actually send a signal to the running process, but instead to the terminal driver.  In that case, `kill -STOP <process>` can send that signal to your process.

Comment: `^Q` is usually SIGKILL as I remember.

Comment: @Hauleth I think it is system dependent. `^U` is SIGKILL on my system.

Comment: While both cygwin/windows and linux recognize the Signal.trap("STOP") line, neither accepts start (though both show the start signal in stty -a).  If I set a trap on STOP, neither will execute the signal handler (a simple puts) when ^S is hit.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR No, you can't trap them, because they don't result in signals and the processes under the terminal don't see them and can only detect them heuristically. However, if the point is to be able to use those keybindings in your terminal program, then yes, you can do that by disabling the terminal's special treatment of them.

`^q` and `^s` don't result in signals. It's `^z` not `^s` that results in the terminal signaling <del>`SIGSTOP`</del> (EDIT: It's actually `SIGTSTP`).

What `^s` does is tell the terminal to not read the output of the processes that are writing to it. This causes the processes to block on write to the terminal (they can still write to other places and read from stdin, as well as do other things)[1]. `^q` tells the terminal to continue reading and displaying the processes output. The processes that have the terminal as standard input don't see these. The terminal sees the keybindings, acts on them, and doesn't pass them on to the processes reading from its terminal device.

You can disable this special behaviour with `stty -ixon`, and re-enable it with `stty ixon`. When I disable it, the process that reads while I type says that `^s` is byte `0x13`, and `^q` is byte `0x11`.

[1] As an experiment to show this, you can open 2 terminal windows. Execute `tty` on the second one to find its terminal device. Then, on the first terminal, you can run `tee $TTY > $OTHER_TTY` with `$OTHER_TTY` being the terminal device of the second terminal. Once you've done that, you can hit `^s` to block writes to the terminal and check this by typing some line. That line will be displayed in the second terminal, but not the first, and thereafter nothing you type will be displayed on either until you hit `^q`. What happened here is that after you hit `^s` and typed a line, `tee` could still read it, and output it to its stdout which we redirected to the second terminal. Then, when it tried to write it to the first file passed as argument it blocked because it was the terminal you blocked with `^s`. It stayed there waiting for `write()` to return which it won't until you hit `^q`.

Comment: Type `stty -a` on your command line to see that the claim is false (at least on my system—and every other system I've used) that `^z` and not `^s` results in `SIGSTOP`.  `^s` is `SIGSTOP`.

Comment: @iconoclast I see `stop = ^S; susp = ^Z` and when I look in `stty`'s manpage I see `stop CHAR: CHAR will stop the output` and `susp CHAR: CHAR will send a terminal stop signal`. So, it really is `^Z` that sends `SIGSTOP`, *not* `^S`.

Comment: @iconoclast Did you assume that `stop` meant that it sent a `SIGSTOP` or are you actually using a system where `susp = ^S`? I'm using Archlinux with urxvt.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean about `^s`, so that part of what I wrote was wrong, but if I write a script that traps `SIGSTOP` it doesn't allow me to react to a `^z` by the user, so I don't see why you're claiming that `^z` sends a `SIGSTOP`.  Can you clarify that part?

Comment: @iconoclast I don't think it would react to a `kill -s SIGSTOP` either. The manpage, `signal(7)`, says: "The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored." So, you can't trap it, otherwise the system wouldn't be able to guarantee `SIGSTOP` behavior.

Comment: @iconoclast If you want to observe `SIGSTOP` behavior, a more reliable approach is to go to the shell, run `cat`, hit `^Z`, then run `ps -o stat= $(pgrep -P $$ cat)`. That should output `T` which means that `cat` is stopped. Another command is, `grep '^State:' "/proc/$(pgrep -P $$ cat)/status"` which should output `State: T (stopped)`.

Comment: @iconoclast "so I don't see why you're claiming that ^z sends a SIGSTOP" -- Also, you might have missed the excerpt of stty's manpage I provided where it says that `susp` means the "CHAR will send a terminal stop signal".

Comment: @iconoclast You know what? Scratch what I said, it's not `SIGSTOP` it's `SIGTSTP`, which coincidentally can be caught. You can see it by running `cat` in one terminal, run `sudo strace -p $(pgrep -n cat)` in another, and then hit `^Z` in the terminal with `cat`. `strace` outputs `--- SIGTSTP {si_signo=SIGTSTP, si_code=SI_KERNEL} ---`.